# Api request into this.state react object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, xmlhttprequest

I want to make an api request to an api, I get the object inside of the `request.onreadystatechange` funtion but after the funtion the variable is just the empty string I used to initialize the variable.

```js
apirequest =  () => {

        let input_search = document.getElementById("search-input-id").value;
        let linkrequest = 'Thelinkfortherequest' + input_search;
        let result = "";
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("get", linkrequest);
        request.send();
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){
                result = JSON.parse(request.response);
                console.log(result); //the outout here is right
            }
        }
        // the output here is the empty string
        console.log(result);
        // i want the response to be in the React component State
        this.setState({jsondata: result});
        this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1})

    }
```

I Tried different soulutions on the internet but nothing worked.
The goal is that the response object is in the jsondata object that I defined in the state

```json
[
  {
    "evse": "US*HTA*E1000207",
    "ts": 13246587,
    "cpo": "test string",
    "tarif": "test string",
    "evse_prefix": "test string",
    "connector": "test string",
    "max_kW": int,
    "currency": "test string",
    "price_min": float,
    "incl_min": int,
    "price_kWh":int,
    "price_session": int,
    "startingDate": "test string",
    "VersionData": int
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all welcome to Stack Overflow!

One fundamental feature with JavaScript is that while it is a single threaded language, it's also event driven. This means that the event loop (the engine executing your tasks) does not wait for *callbacks* to be called before proceding.

What this means is that your callback `request.onreadystatechange` will be *called* asynchronously and by that time, `this.setState` has already been called with empty data!

That's why you should call `this.setState` *when* your data has been fetched like this:

```js
let input_search = document.getElementById("search-input-id").value;
let linkrequest = 'Thelinkfortherequest' + input_search;
let result = "";
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("get", linkrequest);
request.send();
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){
        result = JSON.parse(request.response);
        console.log(result); //the outout here is right
        // i want the response to be in the React component State
        this.setState({jsondata: result}); // <-- update your state here
    }
}
// the output here is the empty string
console.log(result);

this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1})
```